# Как `расширить` диск в Убунте?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил убунту(бионический бобёр) но увы, по глупости оставил "свободное пространство".

Хочу присоединить `не размеченно` (251 ГиБ) к `/dev/sda5` (651 ГиБ), как это можно реализовать ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузиться с livecd/liveusb и правой кнопкой мыши изменить размер нужного раздела

Comment: Resize/Move и вышкой подвинуть раздел пробовали?

Comment: @Denis640Kb пробовал, что-то "держит "

Comment: Не даёт двигать или ошибка при нажатии кнопки изменить размер или переместить?

Comment: Очевидно, раздел нужно предварительно отмонтировать

Comment: @andreymal попробую с диска убунтовского,  такое провернуть  (но увы не сегодня).

Comment: @timob256, попробуйте это сделать программой Disks, она попроще помоему

Comment: https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=expand-linux-disk и https://1cloud.ru/help/linux/uvelichenie_diskovogo_prostranstva_debian_9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо @andreymal.

В общем загрузился с диска DVD-RW на которой стоял Ubuntu . И запустил с него **GParted**.
Там увеличил "длину"(размеры) диска, также он сделал перенос имеющихся данных , это он сам так делает я на это повлиять не мог *(так что это не быстрая штука успел и поесть и помыться)*.

Также он выкинул предупреждения что если что(если при переносе опирационка не запустится) то он не причём. НО у меня всё заработало.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: У gparted live, если чё - есть встроенный скриншотер.

Comment: @donRumata знаю так легче было, да и тревоги я хотел передать